# Django Captcha Decorator

Tags: django, recaptcha

I've used a reCaptcha system created by the [simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/21/how-to-add-recaptcha-to-django-site.html) website.

In class-based views, it works perfectly fine, but whenever it comes to built-in libraries like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
```

and functionalities:

```
auth_views.password_reset
```

it literally does not work as it should. The process of confirming the code of captcha is not executed at all.
I'm having a following usage of it:

```
url(r'^password/reset/$', check_recaptcha(auth_views.password_reset), name='password_reset'),
```

**decorators.py:**

```
def check_recaptcha(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.recaptcha_is_valid = None
        if request.method == 'POST':
            recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
            url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
            values = {
                'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
                'response': recaptcha_response
            }
            data = urllib.urlencode(values)
            req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            result = json.load(response)
            if result['success']:
                request.recaptcha_is_valid = True
            else:
                request.recaptcha_is_valid = False
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
                print(str('Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.'))
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped_view
```

**password_reset_template.html**

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="row main">
          <div class="main-login main-center">
            <center>
            <br>
            <h3 class="card-title"><b>E-mail:</b></h3><br>
            <form method="post" action=".">
              {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    <div class="form-group" style="padding: 0px 40px;">
                      {% if field.errors %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                          {{ field.errors }}
                        </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            {{ field }}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        {% if field.help_text %}
                        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <br>
                <div style="padding: 0px 40px;">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Reset Password</button>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="g-recaptcha"  data-sitekey="xxxxxx"></div>
                <br>
            </form>
            </center>
          </div>
          <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yes, the decorated view is running each time I am sending POST request to this site, nevertheless, I am not able to drop the request due to the fact, that I am not able to check parameter that is being set:
"request.recaptcha_is_valid = False"

Comment: The decorator simply sets a variable `request.recaptcha_is_valid`. It will only work if the wrapped view uses it in a check, e.g. `if form.is_valid() and request.recaptcha_is_valid:`. You can't use the decorator to wrap arbirtrary views like `auth_views.password_reset`, because it doesn't check `request.recaptcha_is_valid`.

Comment: To get a recaptcha with the password reset, I would consider using a custom password reset form that validates the recaptcha. There are libraries that may make this easier.